# Wrong keys on internal Swedish keyboard

Tags: keyboard, catalina

A few weeks ago I had a problem with the § and < keys being "mixed up in software" on my *external* Windows keyboard, (the keys are in the right locations physically). I thought the 10.15.2 update resolved it, but now alt+2 on the *internal* keyboard produces ™ but it should produce @. It used to work fine, problem started some weeks ago, perhaps coinciding with me using the windows keyboard more often... Macbook pro mid 2014 retina, 13 inch.

Comment: There are differences in (Swedish, Swedish Sami) and (Swedish Pro). Which one do you want to use? Check their layout in system preferences and hold alt, shift etc to see how it changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apple input source called Swedish has ™ at Alt 2.  Same for Swedish Sami PC.

The one called Swedish Pro has @ at Alt 2.

So make sure the list at system preferences/keyboard/input sources has only Swedish Pro on it.